# Why does ModelMapper map collections merge-style?

Tags: java, modelmapper

In my application I am mapping data transfer objects to entities using the ModelMapper library.

One entity `Library` has a collection (`java.util.Set`) containing other entities `Book`.
A user should be able to change the collections contents.

In this case a data transfer object `UpdateDTO` is used that contains the identifiers of the entities `Book` to be stored in the collection.

The backend maps the `UpdateDTO` to the entity `Library` using `ModelMapper`.

Now assume a user removing an entity `Book` from the collection of `Library`. The `UpdateDTO` now contains a list of all entities of `Book` without the ones removed by the user.

I expect the collection to be missing the entities `Book` removed by the user when `ModelMapper` maps the `UpdateDTO` to the entity `Library`. But unlike my expectation the entity returned `Library` still contains all `Book` entities.

**Why is that?** I have pinned down the 'problem' to these lines in the `CollectionConverter` [0].

[0] https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/modelmapper/internal/converter/CollectionConverter.java#L62-L63

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository of `ModelMapper` contains an issue [0] regarding the same problem, an explanation on how the current implementation works and code so `ModelMapper` removes items if the source size is less than the destination size.

[0] https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/423

Comment: Another related issue: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/465

Answer (score 3):

Merging lists is true by default, but you can turn it off:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().setCollectionsMergeEnabled(false);
```

See:
http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/